# using bodyparser to post request to server

Tags: express, https, node-modules

const express = require('express')
const express = require('express')

const https = require('https')

const app = express();

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{

res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")
})

app.post('/',(req,res)=>{ // console.log(req.body.cityName);

const query = req.body.cityName;

const appkey = "a602ee18b63e10a1276ceb0896049408";

const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=query&appid=appkey"

https.get(url,(response)=>{

console.log(response.statusCode);

response.on("data",(data)=>

const weatherData =  JSON.parse(data);
const temp = weatherData.main.temp;

const weatherDescription = weatherData.weather[0].description;

const icon = weatherData.weather[0].icon;

res.write("

weather is currently + ' weatherDescription '

");
res.write(

## Tempeartue of city is + "temp"

);

```
  res.send();
});
```

});
});

app.listen(3000,()=>{ console.log("server is running"); });

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not getting result, is res.write() and res.send() deprecated